# Using type parameter as method input

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with sending down Type parameters from one method to another.
It is probably best to illustrate with code...

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        new Test().a(() -> "ABC");
        new Test().a(() -> 42);
        new Test().a(() -> Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public <T, E extends Exception> T a(UpdateFunction<T, E> function) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, E {
        Data<T,E> data = b(new GenericType<T>(){}, new GenericType<E>(){});
        data.data = function.update();
        //TBI: save and process data here
        return data.data;
    }

    public <T, E extends Exception> Data<T, E> b(GenericType<T> type, GenericType<E> exception) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return new Data<T, E>(); //In the real life scenario this takes a lot of code
    }

    public class Data <T, E extends Exception> {
        T data;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface UpdateFunction <T, E extends Exception>{
        T update() throws E;
    }
}
```

I have no idea of how to get the type parameters from `a` into `b`.
In that code example, I am getting

```
IllegalArgumentException: javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T> does not specify the type parameter T of GenericType<T>
```

Probably should not use `GenericType` at all, but I don't know how else to do it

Comment: You can't use something like `GenericType` with a type variable. It only works if you use a concrete type. That said, I see no reason why you would need those in the first place, since you're discarding the result of `b`, you could just call `b()` and be done. i.e. this example is too contrived to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that it wouldn't be possible with GenericType. Also updated the code to possible make it easier to understand why I would want to do it like this

Comment: Have you tried using a class object?

Comment: @bracco23 I've tried to, but I don't now how to instanciate a class from a generic parameter

Comment: This still does not illustrate the problem. The type parameters are already 'passed down' without passing the `GenericType`s. But since you're throwing an `InstantiationException` I guess you're doing something like `Class.forName(type.getType()).newInstance()` ? In java 8 there are much cleaner ways of doing that instantiation. But one way or another, you'd have to pass additional arguments from the call site that actually capture the type information, since generic types are erased.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed the fact that java pass down the types automagically

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered moving the type parameters to the class level?

This way you don't have to "send down Type parameters from one method to another".

```
class Test<T, E extends Exception> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().a(() -> "ABC");
    }

    public void a(UpdateFunction<T, E> function) {
        b();
    }

    public Data b() {
        return new Data();
    }

    public class Data { // Data class has access to T and E
        E e;
        T t;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface UpdateFunction <T, E extends Exception>{
        T update() throws E;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have considered it, but in the real life case I have to use different type parameters to the same instance, so it wouldn't work. The closest I get is sending down the update function to b, but it feels like a dirty hack